# How to implement Document protection for a part of the Document?

Tags: php, document, readonly, phpword, copy-protection

I am working a project where my application generates receipts with final amount calculated for the client in DOCX format using PHPWORD. The client would update only the bank details field in the receipt and return back the receipt to us for payments. I want to protect (or make it un-editable) rest of the area or at least the final amount area in docx file. I am not able to find any resource regarding the same. i was able get data related to how to protect the document as a whole. Please help.

Comment: May need to rethink this. Most people will not open a `.docx` because of the potential for it to carry code.

Comment: Apart from that, what is to stop me recreating the `docx` with a smaller Grand Total and sending that back to you!!??